# Button won't line up with input field when labels are used

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've included an HTML (bootstrap) form that's giving me some trouble. This form needs to have a button to press that generates a new row of fields. I'm not concerned about the functionality of the button yet, however. I just want the damn button to align with the text-box and not the label.

Can someone help me line the '+' button with the text field? I know the problem has been discussed a few times before. I've been trying to figure this out for an embarrassing amount of time. various methods and approaches have been attempted, but I feel I am missing something fundamentally; something obvious.

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mattmolsberry/24dd1bxd/3/)

```
<div class="container col-md-12">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="showName">Show Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showName" placeholder="Enter the show name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="showDate">Date(s) of Show</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showDate" placeholder="Please enter the date(s) of the event.">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="band">Band Name</label>
          <select id="band" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Band</option>;
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="stage">Stage</label>
          <select id="stage" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Stage</option>;
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="speciesnumber1">Show Time</label>
          <input type="time" id="speciesnumber1" name="speciesnumber1" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group" style="vertical-align:bottom">
          <div class="btn btn-danger alignment">+</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 padding-top-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" align="right">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: just add margin to the alignemnt class .alignment {
    margin-top: 23px;
}

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/24dd1bxd/5/

Answer (score 0):

Set the second row container in `display: flex` with `align-items: flex-end`

```
.row1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24dd1bxd/4/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
 @media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
 .padding-top-24{
  padding-top:24px;
 }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container col-md-12">
  <form role="form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="showName">Show Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showName" placeholder="Enter the show name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="showDate">Date(s) of Show</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="showDate" placeholder="Please enter the date(s) of the event.">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="band">Band Name</label>
          <select id="band" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Band</option>;
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="stage">Stage</label>
          <select id="stage" class="form-control">
            <option value="">Select Stage</option>;
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="speciesnumber1">Show Time</label>
          <input type="time" id="speciesnumber1" name="speciesnumber1" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 padding-top-24">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="btn btn-danger alignment">+</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 padding-top-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" align="right">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have added `padding-top-24` css class to `+` button div and add @media css for it for making it responsive.